# Can we do a if Check to API data in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular12

This is mt TS file, in which `_services.liveclasses_api()` points to service.ts with API Get.

```js
this._services.liveclasses_api().subscribe((result)=>{
  console.log(result);
  this.liveclasses = result.data.classes;
})
```

The pinpoint in here is, from API we get Subjects as PHY, Chem, etc.. and we Have to Print as Physics, Chemistry, etc...

```html
<p 
  *ngIf="d.subject == 'CHEM'" 
   class="sess-subject">
   <span>
    <img src="/assets/images/chemistry.png" class="sesssub-icon"alt="" />
    </span>CHEMISTRY
</p>

<p 
  *ngIf="d.subject == 'PHY'" 
  class="sess-subject">
  <span>
   <img src="/assets/images/physics.png" class="sesssub-icon"alt="" />
  </span>Physics
</p>
```

Likewise for all other Subjects. Is there another approach to this, where I can print the subject Name from API Subject Code? Without the `ngIf` on Angular template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on your question, I understand that your API is giving you values such as 'PHY', 'CHEM', etc...

So, instead of checking multiple times like that, you could refactor that logic like this:

```js
// somewhere else in your project, you could have an `enum`
// for getting the values 

//subject.utils.ts for example

export enum mySubjects = {
   'CHEM': 'CHEMISTRY',
   'PHY': 'PHYSICS'
   ....
}

// back in your component, you could handle it like this:
import { MySubjects } from '../subject.utils';
...
...
...

getSubjects(): Observable<YourTypeHere> {
 return this._services.liveclasses_api().pipe(
    map((response) => MySubjects[response.data.classes])
  );
}

getImageSource(mySubject: string): string {
  return `/assets/images/${mySubject.toLowerCase()}.png`
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(formatSubjects$ | async) as subject">
  <p   
     class="sess-subject">
     <span>
     <img 
       [src]="getImageSource(subject)" 
       class="sesssub-icon"alt="" />
     </span>{{ subject }}
  </p>
</ng-container>
```